# Gmail app showing gaps between words on hyperlink underline

Tags: html, email, hyperlink, gmail, marketo

I'm building email templates in Marketo. In the Gmail app for iOS, hyperlink underlines appear broken between hyperlinked words. I'd like the underline to be a solid line with no gaps.

[Screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVniy.jpg)

There is nothing particularly unique about how I have coded the anchor tags:

```html
<a href="${linkUrl}" style="display: inline-block;text-decoration: underline;">${linkText}</a>
```

I'm not experiencing this in any other email clients, and I haven't found anyone else seeking help on this issue. One other funny thing is that when you click the link in gmail, the gaps disappear.

Has anyone experienced anything like this? Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code snippet per se. So the problem might come from something else in the rest of your email. Could you share a complete HTML email code? (with doctype, body and such) Also, which version of iOS are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue with Marketo doing this until today. I checked the HTML of the email & noticed that the words were on separate lines instead of just having a space between them. I replaced the space with a non-breaking space `&nbsp;` and that seemed to fix the issue.